# How to copy values from one property to another in the same object?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, and I want to copy the value of one property to another. The following is the sample code I wrote:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private MyObject()
    {
       intArray = new int[3]{1,2,3}
       int1 = 1;
       SaveCopy();
    }

    private void SaveCopy()
    {
       intArray_Copy = intArray;
       int1_Copy = int1;
    }

    public int[] intArray { get; set; }
    public int int1 { get; set; }
    public int[] intArray_Copy { get; set; }
    public int int1_Copy { get; set; }
}
```

I am writing a `SaveCopy()` function to save the value of `intArray` and `int1`. I understand that using "=" makes a reference to the original property, once the value of the original property changes, the copy will also change. How do I make a copy that is different from the original property?

Comment: Does your code work? In C# you should use type of variable when declaring them. Also read MSDN documentation. If you copy number you copy the value just by the assign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Once the value of the original property changes, the copy will also
>   change

That is the case when talking about [*reference types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx). For example, `int`, which is a [*value type*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), will create a copy of itself on assignment to a new variable.

When dealing with various reference types other than array, for example, one will need to implement a "deep clone" mechanism. There is a great question which describes how to do that on SO: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

For your `int[]`, you can use [`Array.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void Copy()
{
    Array.Copy(sourceArray, destArray, sourceArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: Also to note, as far as I'm aware, for regular objects, there is no built-in functionality to do a deep copy, you'd need a library for that (correct me if I'm wrong?)

Comment: @Rob Yes, there is no deep copying OOTB for reference types. You'll have to implement it yourself / use a thirdparty.